# Error while install vimtex on ubuntu 20.10

Tags: vim

I used to have vim on Ubuntu 19.04. After Upgrade to 20.10, [vimtex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kupWM.png) is not working. I re-installed it but still not compiling.

[image].

In the Github [repo](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex#installation), there seems to be explanation about how to make it work. But I really don't understand exactly.

> If you use the new package feature in Vim, please note the following:
>
> - Make sure to read and understand the package feature: `:help package`!
> - Use the `/pack/foo/start` subdirectory to make sure the filetype plugin is automatically loaded for the tex filetypes.
> - Helptags are not generated automatically. Run `:helptags` to generate them.
> - Please note that by default Vim puts custom `/start/` plugin directories at the end of the `&runtimepath`. This means the built in
>   filetype plugin is loaded, which prevents Vimtex from loading. See
>   [#1413](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/1413) for two suggested solutions to this. To see which scripts are loaded and in which order, use `:scriptnames`.
> - For more information on how to use the Vim native package solution, see [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9522/what-is-the-vim8-package-feature-and-how-should-i-use-it) and [here](https://shapeshed.com/vim-packages/).

Any idea ?

Comment: Your question seems to be more about how to get a plugin running in vim rather than latex itself and, although there are vim users here, I'd suspect that you'll have better luck asking on https://vi.stackexchange.com

Comment: There are several issues concerning E716 filed on [github](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/search?q=e716&type=issues), some are fixed by setting the paths right. Maybe file an issue yourself.